# how to save every value from a dynamic table

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a table that based on the data of my web API. Also, the user have the option to create more rows for new information. It's a table about communication details like kind(mobile phone), another kind(business, private) and the number itself. My first problem is, that it does not set the correct values, all of the fields are empty. My second problem is that it does not save all the rows, it just saves the last row I added or edited.

My Table:

```html
<div id="communicationTitle"> <h3> Kommunikation </h3> <button mat-button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="addCom()" style="height: 35px; margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;"> Hinzufügen </button> </div>
        <div class="communicationTable" >
            <form [formGroup]="persoForm">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="comdataSource" #comTable formGroupName="communication">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="art">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Art </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cType"> 
                      <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select [value]="cType.kommunikationsart.bezeichnung" formControlName="kommunikationsart"> 
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let auswahl of communicationKinds" [value]="auswahl.bezeichnung"> {{auswahl.bezeichnung}} </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="ort">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sorte </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cType"> 
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select [value]="cType.kommunikationsort.bezeichnung" formControlName="kommunikationsort"> 
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let auswahl of communicationSorts" [value]="auswahl.bezeichnung"> {{auswahl.bezeichnung}} </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nummer/Adresse </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cType"> 
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="text" [value]="cType.nummerAdresse" formControlName="kommunikationsnummer">
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="details">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Call </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cType">
                    <button mat-icon-button color="primary" >
                        <mat-icon class="mat-18">
                            call
                        </mat-icon>
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="update">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Std </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cType">
                    
                    <mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-checkbox>
                    
                    </td>
                   
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cType; let i = index">
                        <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="delCom(i)">
                            <mat-icon class="mat-18">delete</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
              </table>
            </form> 
        </div>
```

My Typescript:

```html
//THE FORM
persoForm = new FormGroup({
    
    communication: new FormGroup({
      kommunikationsart: new FormControl(),
      kommunikationsort: new FormControl(),
      kommunikationsnummer: new FormControl(),
    }),
    //--------------------------------------
    //.. some more data which is not necessary for my problem 
 })
 //Setting the standard values from my web api to the form which works for everything but not for my communication table
 getStandardValues(){
  this.persoForm.patchValue({
    communication:{
    kommunikationsart: this.kType.kommunikationsart,
    kommunikationsnummer: this.kType.kommunikationsort,
    kommunikationsort: this.kType.nummerAdresse
    },
  })
}
//Saving the information
onSubmit(){
   console.log(this.persoForm.getRawValue());
}
```

thx in advance

Comment: patching problem generally get from form field key Name and API response key will not same

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your table structure, but if you have one row of data per row in your table, you need to use a form array

Comment: Instead of my formGroupName or what do you mean?